# Pass parameter to Laravel Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

How can I passed a parameter in my middleware? I'm always getting this error 
[image]

Here are the structure of my middlware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SubDomainAccess
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $subdomain)
    {
        dd($subdomain); // Just trying to output the result here
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And on the Kernel.php under the **$routeMiddleware** I added this

```
'subdomain.access' => \App\Http\Middleware\SubDomainAccess::class,
```

Now on my **web.php** route file I added this

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.' . config('site.domain')], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'site.home', 'uses' => 'Site\Listing\ListingController@showListing'])->middleware('subdomain.access');
});
```

Also I tried this

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.' . config('site.domain')], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'subdomain.access'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'site.home', 'uses' => 'Site\Listing\ListingController@showListing']);
    });
});
```

I tried this but nothings working. The only thing I haven't tried is placing the middleware in my controller constructor. But I don't wan't it that way as I think this is messy and it's more elegant if its within the route file.

Hope you can help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I managed to find a way to get the parameters without passing a third parameter on the middleware handle function thanks to this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/middleware-parameters)

So what I did to retrieve the **subdomain** parameter is this

```
$request->route()->parameter('subdomain')
```

or if all parameter

```
$request->route()->parameters()
```

Answer (score 1):

`['middleware' => 'subdomain.access']` is wrong, try to use `['middleware' => 'subdomain:access']` with a `:` instead.

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/passing-parameters-to-middleware-in-laravel-5.1

Comment: Sorry but subdomain.access is the name I placed in the kernel as mentioned on my post. And without the 3rd parameter it's actually going inside my custom middleware so meaning the naming is not the issue. If I add the 3rd parameter that's where I get the problem

Answer (score 0):

Get URI from `$request` object and then return domain. No need to pass subdomain as params to middleware.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SubDomainAccess
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $subdomain)
    {
        $sudomain = $this->getSubDomain($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Get Subdomain name
     * @param $uri
     * @return bool
     */
    private function getSubDomain($uri)
    {
        if(!empty($uri))
        {
            $host = explode('.', $uri);
            if(sizeof($host) > 2)
                return $host[0];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```